# How to use source code of one gwt application in to another application

Tags: gwt

I have two different gwt projects, and want to use classes of one gwt application in to an another module. Is there any way to do that?

I followed the below approach, added below two lines in the second project

```
   <inherits name="com.yellowbook.mdb.NationalResidential"/>
   <source path='com.yellowbook.mdb' />
```

but i am getting the following error:

```
 Unable to find 'com/yellowbook/mdb/NationalResidential.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
```

did i miss any thing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a one project into another one, then following are some of possible ways:

## First approach

If you are using two projects as a separate module i.e. [GWT Module](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/wizards/gwt/module), then you can create a package structure for common code and add entry into gwt.xml file.

ProjectModule1.gwt.xml

```
 <source path='shared'/>
```

ProjectModule2.gwt.xml

```
 <source path='shared'/>
```

## Second approach

If you created separate project for this, then

**In development:**

1. Add module entry in gwt.xml file, i.e.

   ```
   <inherits name='com.project2'/> //same for project 1
   ```
2. Also if you working with eclipse, then add required project in build path for development

**In Production:**

1. You need to create a jar and add to classpath for both the project.

But if you go with second approach, then it is not a very good approach, because when you want to load a project1 then project2 auto load and unnecessary javascript will load, so better to use module approach, or create a third project which has a common code of project1 & project2 and use it in both projects.

Comment: @Igor Klimer - tried the second approach but i am getting some error as edited in the question.Please take a look at it.

Comment: tried the second approach but i am getting some error as edited in the question.Please take a look at it.

Comment: Used above one only, but i am getting the same error as posted in the question. I have added the parent project in the build path under the project tab as well.

Comment: In which package structure the file NationalResidential.gwt.xml file exist?

Comment: Also remove  <source path='com.yellowbook.mdb' /> if it is a part to access/use a second project.

Comment: 'com.yellowbook.mdb' package of project1 and i removed the source as well

Comment: and what is for project2? can I know? because given inherits should work.

Comment: Project2 is a different Gwt project, and i configured this <inherits> tag in that *.gwt.xml file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17101/discussion-between-jagadeesh-and-bhumika)

Comment: Seems like i have missed to add some thing in the project2 to class path.

Answer (score 2):

Beside copy and paste you could write a third GWT module that implements the classes and inherit this new module in both applications. This way you can re-use it anywhere you want.

Comment: I tried one of the approach as updated in the question, but am unable to load as mentioned above.