# Share GWT module between different Grails Plugins

Tags: gwt, grails, plugins, module, share

I have seen in different posts how GWT modules can be shared across different projects.

E.g.
[How to use source code of one gwt application in to another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564362/how-to-use-source-code-of-one-gwt-application-in-to-another-application)

My Case is a little more specific, as I'm having **two Grails+GWT Plugins**: **projectA** and **projectB**.

**projectA** contains java beans in src/java that are both used in the Grails services as well as in the src/gwt code. I have defined a module.gwt.xml that contains the paths to my java beans, which my main module (EntryPoint.gwt.xml) inherits. This works fine for **projectA**.

I have created **projectB** and I want to use the java beans declared in **projectA** in **projectB's** Grails services and src/gwt code. I managed to share the java beans for the services by adding grails.plugin.location.'projectA' =  in the BuildConfig.groovy of projectB. However when I add a  in the main module (EntryPoint.gwt.xml) of **projectB** I get the following error when compiling the GWT modules in **projectB**.

```
Loading inherited module '<qualified module name>'
  |    [ERROR] Unable to find '<qualified module name>' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
  | [ERROR] Line 16: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
```

Any idea how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following property in the BuildConfig.groovy resolved my issue.

gwt.plugins = ["/**name-of-plugin**/"]